# KitKat xml selector applying wrong color based on state

Tags: android, xml

I'm having an issue specific to Kitkat devices and lower, the code works exactly as expected on newer versions of Android. I'm styling a button using a selector, on Kitkat the color of the button is grey (@color/button_disabled_color), but on newer version the color is blue (?attr/colorPrimary). Can't Kitkat use the state correctly or is there something else going wrong here?

The selector looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/button_disabled_color" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
</selector>
```

The button is defined in xml as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
     android:id="@+id/buttonStandard"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:text="@string/standard_button"/>
```

The default button style is specified like below, note this style is set as the default style for buttons in the theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme.ButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@color/primary_button_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_button_text_color</item>
</style>
```

Note that it works fine for the textColor which is done in the exact same way. changing the ?attr/colorPrimary to an actual color specified in the colors.xml also made no difference.

Comment: Turns out there is a default selector being used. To fix this I ended up removing the backgroundTint item and thus the custom selector from the style and updating to the latest Android support library. This was broken in previous versions which is why the code was there in the first place. The default selector makes use of the primary color specified in the theme for enabled buttons. I'm guessing there is a default grey being used when disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Add selector like ..

---

**square_blue.xml**

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/square_blue_pressed"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/square_blue_normal"/>
</selector>`

---

**square_blue_pressed.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/light_blue" />
</shape>`

---

**square_blue_normal.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/dark_blue" />
</shape>`

---

**in layout xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:padding="20dp"
     android:background="@drawable/square_blue"
     android:text="@string/standard_button"/>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this break the default background of the button?